# FORCE run a scheduled task?

Tags: windows, cmd, taskscheduler

Sometimes I will do :

```
SCHTASKS /create /tn "Task Name 123" /XML C:\temp\Task Name 123.xml /F
schtasks /run  /tn "Task Name 123"
```

and the task won't run, it will stay at status "waiting" (not sure what the english term is for that since we're using a French windows...)

If I manually go in the taskschd.msc GUI and right-click - RUN, it will run, but it didn't with the /run command shown above. This somehow confirms the schtasks command versus the right click in GUI don't act the same.

Any idea why? Is there something "pending" that can prevent my task from running , how can I FORCE it to run via command line?

Comment: No, the `SCHTASKS.EXE` utility, nor the COM `Service.Schedule` object have a "force" option to run a scheduled task.  Though the COM object *does* give you more diagnostic information that might tell you why it fails or sticks in a pending state.

Comment: The problem is not with the task itself. The same code runs fine on a lot of computers and once in a while I will notice even though the /run command was sent, when I go check the task is "pending" , If I run it manually it then goes to run fine. Strange ?

Comment: When you do that, are you validating other tasks aren't running and perhaps impeding yours?

Comment: When I notice that, yes I see there are multiple other tasks which are in a pending state too. Is there some kind of mechanism that would prevent my task from running if other tasks are?

Comment: At that point, I believe there might be something wrong with the underlying service running the tasks.  Check `Win32_Service.Name="schedule"` in that case.

Comment: Hmm Ok I will investigate. It's strange because it's not stuck while running, it's simply refusing to run when asked (except when I right click run, which somehow confirms the schtasks command versus the right click in GUI don't act the same).